# GCC destructor behaviour

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, destructor

I've noticed a difference in behaviour for *gcc*'s destructor when compiled under linux and crosscompiled with *mingw*.

On linux the destructor will not get called unless the program terminates normally by itself (returns from `main`). I guess that kind of makes sense if you take signal handlers into account.

On Win32 however, the destructor is called if the program is terminated by say a CTRL-C, but not when killed from the Task Manager.

Why is this? And what would you suggest to make the destructor get called no matter how the process terminates - on Win32 in particular?

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        printf("main\n");
        while(1) {}
    return 0;
}

__attribute__((destructor)) static void mydestructor(void) {
        printf("destructor\n");
}
```

Comment: Well it's not really possible to make the destructor get called in *every* case.  For example, `SIGKILL` won't ever get sent to your program.  The OS will just wipe it out of existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A kill from the process manager on Window is analogous to a kill -9 on Linux - the program is not given the opportunity to clean up.

Comment: I see. And on system shutdown I presume cleanup will be possible since it won't be a hard 'kill -9'?

Comment: If you need stop/start signals, I'd advise hooking into the Windows service framework, or inittab on Linux.